# Order SQL query by the sum of specefic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here is an extract from the fairly large table (SQL Server 2005) I'm querying against:

```
id (primary key) |  account  |  phone  |  employee  | address
------------------------------------------------------------------
1                |   123     |    Y    |    Y       |   N
2                |   456     |    N    |    N       |   N
3                |   789     |    Y    |    Y       |   Y
```

I need to only return the rows that have at least one Y in phone, employee, or address (there are about 10 others not shown here). Then I need to order those results by the number of Y's they have in any of the three.

I've tried getting the "tagTotal" like this:

```
SELECT
SUM(
  CASE WHEN [phone] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN [employee] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN [address] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  )
  FROM table
  GROUP BY id
```

this returns:

```
tagTotal
---------------
2
0
3
```

I'm at a loss on how to combine this with my existing giant query and order by it without adding each column to the group by at the end.

Comment: DO an inline sum since your not needing to sum across rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sum of values you're after is on the same row, you don't need to aggregrate the results, thereby eliminating the need for the group by..

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN [phone] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  + 
CASE WHEN [employee] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  + 
CASE WHEN [address] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Total
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the addition as a column and then order the results.  The aggregation seems unnecessary, at least with the sample data in the question.  There is only one row per `id`.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ((CASE WHEN [phone] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
              (CASE WHEN [employee] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
              (CASE WHEN [address] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
             ) as NumYs
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE NumYs > 0
ORDER BY NumYs DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the ID and ordering by the sum?

```
SELECT id, 
SUM(
  CASE WHEN [phone] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN [employee] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN [address] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as numsum
  FROM table
  ORDER BY numsum
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT
       id, 
       SUM(
           CASE WHEN [phone] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN [employee] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN [address] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ) tagTotal
  FROM table
  GROUP BY id
) x
where x.tagTotal <> 0
order by x.tagTotal desc
```

The inner query is basically yours, with the addition of the Id (which I assume you need) and giving the sum a name. This is then used as the input to the outer query, excluding those with a zero total and sorting with highest sum first.

(Incidentally, this is not a large query. The largest single select statement I have written covered over 250 lines, took 20 minutes to run, and did the daily P&L of a commodity trading company. That was large...)